# Hi, how do I update/change my git credentials

Tags: github, credentials

I have recently created a new Github account, and want to upload my project onto the repository that I created on my new account.

I have tried my level best to change the git credentials in my system, by changing the username and email:

```
git config --global user.name "newusername"
git config --global user.email emailID
```

However, when I try to push the contents onto the Github repository, it shows me the following error:

> remote: Permission to **newusername**/**repositoryname**.git denied to **oldusername**
>   fatal: unable to access 'url': The requested URL returned error: 403

I have tried my best to have the issue resolved, but I am unable to come up with an exact reason and solution on why this issue is occurring. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: hi, the operating system is windows 10

Answer (score -1):

Delete the github credentials in the windows credential manager:
http://www.digitalcitizen.life/credential-manager-where-windows-stores-passwords-other-login-details

Git should ask you again...

Answer (score -1):

So, if you want to see your current setup, you can use

`git config -l`

Finally, if you want to change it you can just open the file. Usually:

`code ~/.gitconfig` if you're on a mac

Cheers!